# Variable Naming Conventions in C++

Tags: c++, variables, naming-conventions

I come from a .NET world and I'm new to writting C++. I'm just wondering what are the preferred naming conventions when it comes to naming local variables and struct members.

For example, the legacy code that I've inheritted has alot of these:

```
struct MyStruct
{
   TCHAR           szMyChar[STRING_SIZE];
   bool            bMyBool;
   unsigned long   ulMyLong;
   void*           pMyPointer;
   MyObject**      ppMyObjects;
}
```

Coming from a C# background I was shocked to see the variables with hungarian notation (I couldn't stop laughing at the pp prefix the first time I saw it).

I would much rather name my variables this way instead (although I'm not sure if capitalizing the first letter is a good convention. I've seen other ways (see links below)):

```
struct MyStruct
{
   TCHAR           MyChar[STRING_SIZE];
   bool            MyBool;
   unsigned long   MyLong;
   void*           MyPointer;
   MyObject**      MyObjects;
}
```

My question: Is this (the former way) still a preferred way to name variables in C++?

References:

http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html

http://www.syntext.com/books/syntext-cpp-conventions.htm

http://ootips.org/hungarian-notation.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That kind of Hungarian Notation is fairly useless, and possibly worse than useless if you have to change the type of something. ([The *proper* kind of Hungarian Notation](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) is a different story.)

I suggest you use whatever your group does. If you're the only person working on the program, name them whatever way makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Your 2nd statement is totally wrong, you should never develop with this kind of motto. You never know who is gonna work on the project after you. Your naming should **make your code explicit** to you, your future-you and other people. Variables/functions names should help understand what is happening.

Comment: In what way is it wrong? Naming variables in a way that makes sense to you *is* making your code explicit to your future self, if you have any coding experience at all.

Answer (score 19):

The most important thing is to be consistent.  If you're working with a legacy code base, name your variables and functions *consistently* with the naming convention of the legacy code.  If you're writing new code that is only interfacing with old code, use your naming convention in the new code, but be consistent with yourself too.

Answer (score 16):

No. 
The "wrong hungarian notation" - especially the pp for double indirection - made some sense for early C compilers where you could write

```
int * i = 17;
int j = ***i;
```

without even a warning from the compiler (and that might even be valid code on the right hardware...).

The "true hungarian notation" (as linked by head Geek) is IMO still a valid option, but not necessarily preferred. A modern C++ application usually has dozens or hundreds of types, for which you won't find suitable prefixes.

I still use it locally in a few cases where I have to mix e.g. integer and float variables that have very similar or even identical names in the problem domain, e.g.

```
float fXmin, fXmax, fXpeak; // x values of range and where y=max
int   iXmin, iXMax, iXpeak; // respective indices in x axis vector
```

---

However, when maintaining legacy code that does follow some conventions consistently (even if loosely), you should stick to the conventions used there - at least in the existing modules / compilation units to be maintained.

My reasoning: The purpose of coding standards is to comply with the principle of least surprise. Using one style consistently is more important than which style you use.

Answer (score 6):

What's to dislike or mock about "ppMyObjects" in this example apart from it being somewhat ugly? I don't have strong opinions either way, but it does communicate useful information at a glance that "MyObjects" does not.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers here. Either continue using the style that you are given from the handed down for consistency's sake, or come up with a new convention that works for your team. It's important that the team is in agreement, as it's almost guaranteed that you will be changing the same files. Having said that, some things that I found very intuitive in the past:
Class / struct member variables should stand out - I usually prefix them all with m_
Global variables should stand out - usuall prefix with g_
Variables in general should start with lower case
Function names in general should start with upper case
Macros and possibly enums should be all upper case
All names should describe what the function/variable does, and should never describe its type or value.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a hungarian notation person myself, because I find that it lends readability to the code, and I much prefer self-documenting code to comments and lookups.

That said, I think you can make a case for sacrificing your preferred style and some additional maintainability for team unity. I don't buy the argument of consistency for the sake of uniform code readability, especially if your reducing readability for consistency... it just doesn't make sense. Getting along with the people you work with, though, might be worth a bit more confusion on types looking at variables.

Answer (score 1):

Hungarian notation was common among users of the Win32 and MFC APIs. If your predecessors were using that, you can probably best continue using it (even though it sucks). The rest of the C++ world never had this brain-dead convention, so don't use it if you're using something other than those APIs.

Comment: Hungarian notation is most elaborate in MFC, but other parts of the C++ world use a minimal subset of such notation, such as m_ for "member" and p for "pointer".

Answer (score 1):

I think that you will still find that most shops that program in Visual C++ stick with hungarian notation or at least a watered down version of it. In our shop, half of our app is legacy C++ with a shiny new C# layer on top (with a managed C++ layer in the middle.) Our C++ code continues to use hungarian notation but our C# code uses notation like you presented. I think it is ugly, but it is consistent.

I say, use whatever your team wants for your project. But if you are working on legacy code or joining a team, stick with the style that is present for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Its all down to personal preference. I've worked for 2 companies both with similar schemes, where member vars are named as m_varName. I've never seen Hungarian notation in use at work, and really don't like it, but again down to preference. My general feel is that IDE's should take care of telling u what type it is, so as long as the name is descriptive enough of what it does ( m_color, m_shouldBeRenamed ), then thats ok. The other thing i do like is a difference between member variable, local var and constant naming, so its easy to see what is happening in a function and where the vars come from.
Member: m_varName
Const: c_varName
local: varName

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer CamelCase, indeed mostly I've seen people using CamelCase in C++. Personaly I don't use any prefixes expect for private/protected members and interfaces:

```
class MyClass : public IMyInterface {
public:
    unsigned int PublicMember;
    MyClass() : PublicMember(1), _PrivateMember(0), _ProtectedMember(2) {}
    unsigned int PrivateMember() {
        return _PrivateMember * 1234; // some senseless calculation here
    }
protected:
    unsigned int _ProtectedMember;
private:
    unsigned int _PrivateMember;
};
// ...
MyClass My;
My.PublicMember = 12345678;
```

**Why I decided to omit prefixes for public members:**
Because public members could be accessed directly like in structs and not clash with private names. Instead using underscores I've also seen people using first lower case letter for members.

```
struct IMyInterface {
    virtual void MyVirtualMethod() = 0;
};
```

Interfaces contains per definition only pure virtual methods that needs to be implemented later. However in most situation I prefer abstract classes, but this is another story.

```
struct IMyInterfaceAsAbstract abstract {
    virtual void MyVirtualMethod() = 0;
    virtual void MyImplementedMethod() {}
    unsigned int EvenAnPublicMember;
};
```

See [High Integrity C++ Coding Standard Manual](http://www.codingstandard.com/HICPPCM/) for some more inspiration.

Comment: I believe you meant to say that YOU prefer "Pascal" case (which I prefer and most C# developers know it to be the standard for the majority, plenty of references online to back this up). Camel case "myVirtualMethod"   reference: "CamelCase (camel case) is a term which refers to the practice of writing compound words where the first letter of an identifier is lowercase and the first letter of each subsequent concatenated word is capitalized."

Comment: The name `_PrivateMember` is reserved to the compiler.

Comment: @phresnel: I don't think this is true. And yes, there are internal C/C++ methods with _ prefix, but also with __ prefix. But your own class is a kind of seperate namespace where you are free to use whatever prefix you want.

Comment: See _17.4.3.1.2 Global names_: Certain sets of names and function signatures are __always__ reserved to the implementation: * Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an upper-
case letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use._. You are 50% correct: _Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace._

Answer (score 1):

My team follows this [Google C++ code convention](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names):

This is a sample of variable name:

```
string table_name;  // OK - uses underscore.
string tablename;   // OK - all lowercase.

string tableName;   // Bad - mixed case.
```

Comment: Why is tableName bad? It is more readable than tablename to me.

Comment: @toddwz Because an Overlord decided it is. :P

Comment: I would say `tablename` is Bad as opposed to `tableName`

Comment: `tableName` is bad because C++ std lib (atleast the modern additions) use snake case (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)
Mixing `snake_case` and `camelCase` is bad IMHO. I code in Java which uses camel cases everwhere, and python which uses snake cases everywhere -- both look neat. Mixture of snake case and camel case make me squint.

Answer (score 0):

If you use CamelCase the convention is to Capitalize the first letter
for classes structs and non primitive type names, and lower case the first letter for data members.
Capitalization of methods tends to be a mixed bag, my methods tend to be verbs and are already distingished by parens so I don't capitalize methods.

Personally I don't like to read CamelCase code and prefer underscores lower case for
data and method identifiers, capitalizing types and reserving uppercase for acronyms
and the rare case where I use a macro (warning this is a MACRO).