# C++ Naming variables

Tags: c++, variables, naming

In many examples of code that I've seen, they name their variable in a specific way.

E.g.

```
class obj
{
    int mInt;
}
```

or

```
bool gTexture;
```

Questions.

1. Why do they name them in such way, and there are for sure more ways, I think...
2. How do you name them, and why?

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234866/variable-naming-conventions-in-c?rq=1

Comment: Here the `m` and `g` prefixes probably stand for `m`ember and `g`lobal. Our coding standard where I work says we use `d_` for data members and `s_` for static members. Raw pointers have a `_p` suffix.

Comment: Yeah, our coding standards where I work says, that we use no prefixes, suffixes nor underscores. And so what? You should choose a naming standard your company/team uses or follow some publicly available guidelines, such as Microsoft ones (it'll make reading your code easier for people outside your company).

Comment: As blue points out, this question has been done to death, and it's a prototypical holy war.

Comment: Note that a lot of these naming conventions would be irrelevant if other, more important conventions, were followed. Such as not using global variables, not writing functions with more than a handful of lines, having small parameter lists in functions, following the principle of single responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m in mInt represents that the int is a member variable, while the g in gTexture denotes the variable being global.

This comes from Hungarian Notation.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation

Answer (score 0):

Naming is personally. To answer your second question, I don't use such a naming convention, and I append an underscore to class attributes.

Companies have often naming conventions. You may want to have alook at Google's naming conventions: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#General_Naming_Rules

Comment: Now_I_have_at_least_one_reason_not_to_want_to_work_at_Google_

Answer (score 0):

The example you have given uses 'm' for member varibles and 'g' for globals. This is something that is used by some people. It makes it easy to see in a member function (when the function is a bit larger than a few lines, so you can't just look up at the top of the function to see the name of the parameters, local variables and so on), what is "local variable" and what affects "outside of the function".

If you work for a company, in a school or on an open source project, most likely, there is a coding standard that tells what the naming convention is. If it's your personal project, then decide on something you think works for you. The main point is that it's consistent. If not ALL member variables start with 'm', and not all global variables start with 'g', then it's pretty pointless to have it some places - just gives a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't to follow a specific notation but it's cool if you do.

All is about clarity of your code, a variable without any upper case is truly less understandable than a variable with a good synthax. (At the first view, when you look quickly a part of code)

For a clear code, I can recommend the google's norme for c++ code : http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Answer (score 0):

> Why do they name them in such way, and there are for sure more ways, I think...

Generally it is difficult to understand other people's code; If enough time passes, it is difficult to understand your own code as well.

Because of this, software teams set up conventions to make sure the code their team writes is as similar as possible to the code they themselves would have written.

This refers to structuring code, used elements (interfaces, classes, namespaces, etc), naming functions and variables, what to document and in which format, and so on.

When done properly and consistently, it has a significant effect of shortening code maintenance time within a team.

There are a few known conventions, mostly from the conventions used in implementing large code bases and used libraries.

Java tends to use `camelCaseNotation` (start with small letter, use no underscores, capitalize each word).

MFC used the Hungarian notation, where variable names are prefixed with a few letters specifying scope and type of data (m_XXX for member variables, g_XXX for globals, s_XXX for statics, etc).

In particular the Hungarian convention can be gotten right (by using prefixes for semantic information) or horribly wrong (by using prefixes for syntactical information).

(MFC got it horribly wrong.)

ANSI C++ (and std:: namespace) tends to use `small_letters_with_underscores` for identifiers.

There are others and most software teams set up a convention that is a variation of one of the big ones.

> How do you name them, and why?

These days I follow the ANSI C++ conventions, mostly because I want my code to integrate seamlessly with library code. I also think it looks simple and obvious (and this is very subjective).

I rarely use one letter variables (only when the meaning is clear) and prefer full words, to shortened ones.

Examples:

indexes: `int index, line_index, col_index;`

class names: `class recordset; class task_details;` etc.

Answer (score -1):

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation
2. Not a real question. Everyone name them as they want to. You may read these guidelines, though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: This is NOT showing an example of "Hungarian notation", however.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Have you actually read the article I linked to? `g_nWheels : member of a global namespace, integer; m_nWheels : member of a structure/class, integer`

Comment: @MatsPetersson The Wikipedia article specifically mentions `m` as an extended form of Hungarian notation used in C++. +1 to undo the downvote, even though "Do not use Hungarian notation" is too inflexible for my taste.

Comment: @RickYorgason I removed that yet before your comment :) Microsoft suggests not to use it and privately I don't like it, but it doesn't mean, that it shouldn't be used by everyone. And I linked to MS naming conventions as an example of general set of naming rules, which *may* be a base for a global naming convention (one, that everyone should follow). Actually, 95% of C# code I saw on the Internet usually follows them :)

Comment: Ok, so my understanding of Hungarian notation is that the variable is prefixed with for example `b` for boolean, `i` or `n` for integer/count, etc. Then added to that, `m` or `g` for member or global variables. But I have certainly seen examples of naming convention SIMPLY for members and globals (and sometimes function arguments) - and I guess one could argue that it's the same principle, but clearly, unless you change a member variable to a local or some such, changing it's type does not require the name to change if you have only `g` and `m` as prefixes.